# How to give all permissions in voice channel discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Sorry for my stupid question, but i dont understand how to add all permissions in my voice channel for one user. I have this `await channel.set_permissions(member, some_permission)`, but i dont know what permission i need to use

Comment: Sorry for my broken english. And thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "all permissions"?

Comment: I just need to give only one user all permissions only for this channel (edit name, change bitrate, change user limit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just make a role with those permissions and then give that role to the user. for example, `await member.add_roles(var)` var being the role and member being the member you want to add the role too.